# Buy and Sell Stock, with O( n log n ) time complexity

Tags: java, divide-and-conquer

EDIT:
I appreciate the help from both of you but I have to stay with the bound of O( n log n ) time completicty and have to use the divide and conquer technique with binary recursion. I did not make that very clear in the initial posting

I have an unsorted array of ints where I have to buy stock on the ith day and sell it on the jth day for a maximum profit where the ith(the smaller value) day has to come before the jth(the larger value) day. So far i have found a solution that returns the purchase and sell days( index values of the array) and the max profit but it has a O(n^2) time complexity and I am having a hard time getting to the O(n log n) time complexity and implementing divide and conquer

```
public static Profit BestProfit( int[] a, int i, int j )
{
   Profit bestProfit = new Profit();

   int n = j; 
   int maxProfit = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for(j = i; j < n; j++)
      {
         if(a[j] - a[i] > maxProfit)
         {
            maxProfit = a[j] - a[i];
            bestProfit.setBuy( i );
            bestProfit.setSell( j );
            bestProfit.setMaxProfit( maxProfit );
         }
      }
   return bestProfit;
   }
```

The params i is that start of the array and j in the end of the array
The Profit class is a class that I created to hold buy, sell, and profit values.

The three case that I have found that I need to account for are the largest profit for the first half of the array, largest profit for the second half of the array, and the case where the smallest value is on the 1st half of the array and the largest value is on the 2nd half of the array(I have already completed this part of the problem with a simple min/max function that solves the final case).

I am stuck and any help with the divide and conquer implementation or tips of tricks would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I Edited to agregate divide and conquer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In O(n), pretty simple:

```
public static Profit bestProfit(int[] a, int begin, int end) {
    Profit bestProfit = new Profit();
    int min = a[begin];
    int max = a[begin];
    int index = begin;
    int buy = 0;
    int sell = 0;
    int minIndex = begin;
    int maxIndex;
    int maxProfit = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        int n = a[i];
        if (n < min) {
            minIndex = index;
            min = n;
            max = n;
        } else if (max < n) {
            max = n;
            maxIndex = index;
            if (maxProfit < (max - min)) {
                maxProfit = max - min;
                buy = minIndex;
                sell = maxIndex;
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    bestProfit.setBuy(buy);
    bestProfit.setSell(sell);
    bestProfit.setMaxProfit(maxProfit);
    return bestProfit;
}
```

EDITED: with divide and conquer:

```
public static int divideAndConquer(int[] a, int i, int j, Profit profit, int min) {
    int minResult;
    if (i+1 >= j) {
        minResult = Math.min(a[i], min);
        if (a[i] - min > profit.getMaxProfit()) {
            profit.setBuy(min);
            profit.setSell(a[i]);
            profit.setMaxProfit(a[i] - min);
        }
    } else {
        int n = (j+i)/2;
        minResult = divideAndConquer(a, i, n, profit, min);
        minResult = divideAndConquer(a, n, j, profit, minResult);
    }
    return minResult;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] prices = {20, 31, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 0, 8, 7, 7, 4, 1,10};
    Profit profit =new Profit();
    divideAndConquer(prices, 0, prices.length, profit, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(profit);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from both of you but I have to stay with the bound of O( n log n ) time completicty and have to use the divide and conquer technique with binary recursion. I did not make that very clear in the initial posting.

Comment: Edited: with divide and conquer and binary recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve it into O(n) with only three loops:

- First loop to build minimum arrays
- Second loop to build maximum arrays
- Third loop to find the maximum profit

More or less:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] stockPrices = {2, 9, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 0, 8, 7, 7, 4, 1};

    int[] mins = new int[stockPrices.length - 1];
    int[] minsIndex = new int[stockPrices.length - 1];
    int[] maxs = new int[stockPrices.length - 1];
    int[] maxsIndex = new int[stockPrices.length - 1];

    int minIndex = -1;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < stockPrices.length - 1; i++) {
        if (stockPrices[i] < min) {
            min = stockPrices[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
        mins[i] = min;
        minsIndex[i] = minIndex;
    }

    System.out.println("mins idx: " + Arrays.toString(minsIndex));
    System.out.println("mins: " + Arrays.toString(mins));

    int maxIndex = -1;
    int max = -1;
    for (int i = stockPrices.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (stockPrices[i] > max) {
            max = stockPrices[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
        maxs[i - 1] = max;
        maxsIndex[i - 1] = maxIndex;
    }

    System.out.println("maxs idx: " + Arrays.toString(maxsIndex));
    System.out.println("maxs: " + Arrays.toString(maxs));

    int maxProfit = -1;
    int buyIndex = -1;
    int sellIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < stockPrices.length - 1; i++) {
        int profit = maxs[i] - mins[i];
        if (profit > maxProfit) {
            maxProfit = profit;
            buyIndex = minsIndex[i];
            sellIndex = maxsIndex[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("buy at: " + buyIndex + " sell at: " + sellIndex + " profit: " + maxProfit);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from both of you but I have to stay with the bound of O( n log n ) time completicty and have to use the divide and conquer technique with binary recursion. I did not make that very clear in the initial posting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you express the need of using divide and conquer, I will give another answer.

Let say that the stock price is defined in an array: [p0, p1, ..., pn].

We can divide this problem into sub-problems into this definition.

```
max profit = max(maxprofit([p0], [p1..pn]), maxprofit([p0..p1], [p2..pn]), ..., maxprofit([p0..pn-1], [pn]))
```

The first argument for maxprofit is the array of buying prices and the second one is the array of selling prices.

### Look into the first sub-problem

```
maxprofit([p0], [p1..pn])
```

We can divide this even more:

```
maxprofit([p0], [p1..pn]) = max(maxprofit([p0], [p1]), maxprofit([p0],[p2..pn]))
```

We can solve `max([p0], [p1])` since it's a base problem where profit = p1-p0. Now we keep the result, and **cache** it. Continue with breaking down `maxprofit(([p0], [p2..pn])` and keep caching all the solution.

### Look into the second sub-problem

This is the problem:

```
maxprofit([p0..p1], [p2..pn])
```

Can be broken down into:

```
maxprofit([p0..p1], [p2..pn]) = max(maxprofit([p0], [p2..pn]), maxprofit([p1], [p2..pn]))
```

What's interesting: you don't have to break down `maxprofit([p0], [p2..pn])` because you already have it in your cache when working on the first sub-problem. Therefore only the second sub-sub-problem need to be broken down.

I guess at this point you already get where this is going. Basically you need to keep breaking down the problem until you get into a base problem or if the problem is already cached.